# Deploy PHP to Azure Website

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012, azure, cloud

I have come across many tutorials on deploying a PHP website as an Azure Website via a Visual Studio Cloud Project. They all seem out of date and I can't seem to get any working.

My aim is to take an Expression Engine powered site with MySQL db and deploy to Azure using Visual Studio.

The problems I have encountered are:

- The Fast CGI type is unavailable in my version of Visual Studio (2012)
- I haven't seen any instructions on where exactly the PHP code should go

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need Visual Studio to deploy a PHP site to Azure Websites. Check this tutorial: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-create-web-sites/

You can deploy the site using FTP or source control.